# Emptying huge div from HTML using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, huge-pages

I have some problems with deleting huge div from my html using javascript (+jquery or whatever). Actually it takes too much time and I'm looking for faster solution, because it's unacceptable long. Div is really huge, it contains about 13k lines, and i need to change these lines for another ones on user demand (appending new lines takes much less, than removing old...).
I've tried:

1)

```
var old = document.getElementById("data");
var new = document.createElement("div");
newLogDiv.id = "data";
document.body.replaceChild(new, old);
```

2)

```
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "";
```

3)

```
$("#data").html("");
```

4)

```
$("#data").empty();
```

And nothing works fine for me. Looking for the faster solution

Comment: `document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = ""` should be faster

Comment: @Murali nope, dont use innerHTML please. Its bad

Comment: it should be $("#data").html(""); instaed of $("data").html("");

Comment: Why don't you use CSS? Instead of removing the old HTML, set it to display:none, and then append the new lines, which is fast as you said.

Comment: @MentalRay 13 thousand lines of html already in dom + another chunk =  make his browser crawl !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change the style of the div like this:

```
old.style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Hey, that's great. I'm pretty sure, that i can use it.

Answer (score -1):

Use `removeChild` instead of `innerHTML`.

It performs [much faster](http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-removechild)

```
var dataNodes = document.getElementById("data");

while (dataNodes.firstChild) {
    dataNodes.removeChild(dataNodes.firstChild);
}
```

Comment: Too slow. It isn't faster than other methods that i've tested